# Polyhedron = polytope + polyhedral cone, how does it look graphically?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, convex-optimization, polyhedra

We have learned that a polyhedron is the sum of a polytope and a polyhedral cone, but how do you know this graphically?

For example if you're a given polyhedron on paper and you have to determine which part is the polytope and which part is the cone, how do you do that?

I have looked in my notes and can't find anything on this.

Do you know any graphical examples?

Answer (score -1):

A polyhedron can either be bounded, and in this case it is called a polytope, or it can be unbounded, and it is then a polyhedral cone.

Saying that a polyhedron is the sum of a polytope and a polyhedral cone is just another way of saying this.

Graphically, if the polyhedron is "opened" it is a polyhedral cone, and if it is closed, it is a polytope.

Comment: it ir really always one or the other? Can't the polyhedron have both the polytope and the cone at the same time?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: This is not correct. An unbounded polyhedron need not be a polyhedral cone. Remember, a polyhedral cone is closed under positive multiplication, which necessarily means it contains the origin (or at least its closure does). An unbounded polyhedron need not contain the origin.

Comment: so how do I know if given a polyhedron, which part is the cone and which one the polytope?